# Istio best practice for managing microservices and monolith services in same k8s tenant for common usage

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am new in istio therefore might be nonsense question but I would like to understand the best approach.. I have these namespaces as below in k8s.. So currently the microservice running in hub-dev can able to access PostgreSQL where the istio is disabled for database namespace.

1. How could it be possible in `STRICT` mode or did I do something wrong or analyse a wrong way? So it means pod in mesh can talk with another pod which is not meshed, but the other pod can not talk any other pod which is meshed ?

as you can see here, seems my application can talk with database

```
[2021-01-15T15:21:38.601Z] "GET /userinfo?t=1610724097377 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" 0 236 5 3 "95.0.145.40,10.6.0.24" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36" "34130335-b0dd-4cca-b157-f612e3767c9c" "oneapihub-auth-dev" "127.0.0.1:50002" inbound|80|| 127.0.0.1:51230 10.6.19.251:50002 10.6.0.24:0 outbound_.80_._.oneapihub-auth-dev.hub-dev.svc.cluster.local default
[2021-01-15T15:21:38.608Z] "- - -" 0 - "-" 374 778 10012 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "10.6.5.95:64000" outbound|64000||my-postgres-postgresql-helm.database.svc.cluster.local 10.6.19.251:50024 10.254.134.161:64000 10.6.19.251:47396 - -
```

I have some monolith service running `analytics`  namespace where these services needs to connect `logging` and `monitoring` likewise the microservices running in hub-dev .. So if I enabled Istio for `logging` and `monitoring`, the services running in analytics namespace could not able to access the services running in `logging` and `monitoring` , am I right? so should ı create another ELK or prometheus instances ?

So what is the best approach to manage this flow ?

```
$ kubectl get ns --show-labels
NAME              STATUS   AGE     LABELS

database          Active   319d    name=database
analytics         Actice.  20d.    name=analytics      
hub-dev           Active   46h     istio-injection=enabled
istio-system      Active   2d8h    istio-injection=disabled
logging           Active   133d    purpose=logging
monitoring        Active   291d    name=monitoring,namespace=monitoring
```

And here is peerauthentication

```
$ kubectl get peerauthentication -n istio-system -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
  kind: PeerAuthentication
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"security.istio.io/v1beta1","kind":"PeerAuthentication","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"default","namespace":"istio-system"},"spec":{"mtls":{"mode":"STRICT"}}}
    name: default
    namespace: istio-system
  spec:
    mtls:
      mode: STRICT
```

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in both cases:

1. A service that is outside of the mesh, can't talk to a service within the mesh, when strict mode is enabled, but vice-versa is possible.
2. If `logging` and `monitoring` get into the mesh, indeed, `analytics` can't communicate with it, when `STRICT` mode is enabled.

Comment: Would it be good practice to mesh `logging` and `monitoring` but use PERMISSE mode ? Is it make sense ?

Comment: If you want my opinion, I wouldn't put `logging` and `monitoring` into the mesh at all. I would only put the app itself. But I don't know your use case... Also note that PERMISSIVE doesn't mean no mTLS. It will be mTLS within the mesh, and plain text outside. So, yes, I guess it does make sense.

Comment: What is the reason in your point of view to not mesh `logging`and `monitoring`? Cause of they are common instance ? If yes then it would be make sense mesh `database` cause only microservices are  using this database

Comment: Because I use Istio for traffic management and security. I am not counting observability here. `logging` and `monitoring` do not really need neither of these features from Istio. It would be enough for me with Kubernetes features (both traffic management and k8s security). Besides the `logging` and `monitoring` are not really part of your app, so when you put these services into the mesh, all the observability gets a little distorted, because now it is measuring these services as well.

Comment: Make sense really now.. Last question, what about databases like redis and postgresql ? I believe then it make sense to mesh redis and postgresql to observe whole traffic to understand whats wrong in this application, right?

Comment: Well, databases are a little spicy when there is a proxy, in front of them. I believe redis should work, but I have a feeling that you are going to fight with Postgres. That was my experience couple of years ago (when Istio was very new). I built a mesh with envoy proxies, but mysql envoy proxy was not mature enough. So, there were lots of complications (I don't even remember them). I checked and envoy now has postgres filters. Basicly it will depend on envoy if you can do it or not. But yes, the databases can go into the mesh.